# Error in Opening a database in Berkeley DB using C

Tags: c, berkeley-db

I have a structure

```
struct pearson_record{
    unsigned char *src;
    unsigned char *dst;
    unsigned char type;
    float rho;
};

DB *dbp;
int ret;
if ((ret = db_create(&dbp, NULL, 0)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "db_create: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
    exit (1);
}
```

In this structure I have to store values, but right now i get an error in opening the db itself saying access.db: Permission denied.

```
if ((ret = dbp->open(dbp, NULL, DATABASE, NULL, DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0664)) != 0) {
    dbp->err(dbp, ret, "%s", DATABASE);     
}
```

Why do we see a Permission denied error???

Comment: Could be that you don't have write permission to wherever it wants to open a database file. Try running your program like this: $ strace ./myprogram  2>&1 | grep open

Comment: @Tom: that doesn't work.......

Comment: What does your API documentation say the parameters for -> open are?  They have changed over the years, so I'm not sure what parameters you are passing.  Are you trying to create an in-memory database?

Comment: Going off of http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/dbopen.html -- what is DATABASE in your open call?  Is it a path?

Comment: @Joe: DATABASE is a .db file.#define DATABASE "access.db"

Comment: What directory is your program running in?   If you change DATABASE to be a full path to a location you can write to (even /tmp/access.db, for testing) does that work?

Comment: So, when you were trying before, where was it executing from?  Odds are the working directory is somewhere you don't expect it to be...

Comment: @user537670 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2706/discussion-between-joe-and-user537670)

Comment: @user537670 Why didn't it work?